# Oracle: use index for searching null values

Tags: oracle

I've done some search but I prefer something like an hint or similar

http://www.dba-oracle.com/oracle_tips_null_idx.htm

http://www.oracloid.com/2006/05/using-index-for-is-null/

Comment: @Gik25 - I'm not sure that I understand the question.  An Oracle b-tree index does not index NULL values if you're indexing a single column.  A hint in a query is not going to be able to affect what rows are in the index.  There are various approaches to creating indexes that could index NULL values, as you've found, but that requires creating the indexes with the idea of searching for NULL values in mind.

Comment: How many distinct values in the column you are interested in referencing? Bitmap indexes do store nulls, but they have their own performance characteristics and quirks so they are not a drop-in replacement for a BTree index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're asking, "How can I create an index that would allow it to be used when searching for NULL values on a particular field", my suggestion is to create an index on the field you're interested in PLUS the primary key field(s).  Thus, if you've got a table called A_TABLE, with field VAL that you want to search for NULLs, and a primary key named PK, I'd create an index on (VAL, PK).

Share and enjoy.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to "answer" the non-question above.

The articles you link to are kinda right - Oracle's b-tree indexes will not capture when the leaf nodes are null. Take this example:

```
CREATE TABLE MYTABLE (
  ID  NUMBER(8) NOT NULL,
  DAT VARCHAR2(100) 
);

CREATE INDEX MYTABLE_IDX_1 ON MYTABLE (DAT);

/* Perform inserts into MYTABLE where some DAT are null */

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MYTABLE WHERE DAT IS NULL;
```

The ending `SELECT` will not be able to use the index, because the leafs (right-most column) will not capture the nulls. Burleson's solution is stupid, because now you have to use a NVL in all your queries and have compromised the data in the tables. Gorbachev's method includes a known `NOT NULL` column for the leaves of the b-tree, but this expands the index for no reason. Maybe in his case the index made sense that way for tuning other queries, but if all you want to do is find the `NULL`s then the easiest solution is to make the leaf a constant.

```
CREATE INDEX MYTABLE_IDX_1 ON MYTABLE (DAT, 1);
```

Now, the leaves are all the constant (1), and by default the nulls will all be together (either at the top or bottom of the index, but it doesn't really matter as Oracle can use the index forwards or backwards). There is a slight storage penalty for that constant, but a single number is smaller than most other data fields in a typical table. Now the database can use the index when querying for nulls...if the optimizer finds that the best way to get the data.

Comment: My concern with using a constant for the second field in the index is that it might cause slowness during DELETEs as all the duplicates might be searched sequentially. I've had problems that way in other database products - not sure if it's an issue for Oracle or not.

Comment: The index will always (behind-the-scenes) store the ROWID of the record which created that index entry as the last "column". That is, the database should not need to go sequentially through all the (NULL,1) entries in the index, as the ROWIDs are also included in the sorting.

Answer (score 2):

What about a functional index using NVL2, like;

```
CREATE TABLE foo (bar INTEGER);
INSERT INTO foo VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO foo VALUES (NULL);
CREATE INDEX baz ON foo (NVL2(bar,0,1));
```

and then;

```
DELETE plan_table;
EXPLAIN PLAN FOR SELECT * FROM foo WHERE NVL2(bar,0,1) = 1;
SELECT operation, object_name FROM plan_table;
```

should give you

```
OPERATION        OBJECT_NAME
---------------- -----------
SELECT STATEMENT
TABLE ACCESS     FOO
INDEX            BAZ        << yep
```